# New install of Plex Server not opening on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, plex

Installed the latest build of Plex Server (1.31.2.6810-a607d384f, March 14, 2023) on my Win11 64 bit machine this morning. The app won't open. Have tried to open it a couple of different ways... through Windows Start Menu, by clicking on the "Plex Media Server.exe" icon in c:/program files, no luck. Nothing happens when I try to open. Have tried to temporarily turn off antivirus. Have also checked Windows Defender firewall and the firewall is allowing plex access. So I don't know what else it could be. I did not close all apps before installing so maybe a uninstall/reboot/clean reinstall? That seems kinda drastic though. Any other ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. An uninstall/reinstall did the trick.